# I can not mount the part TYPE partition

Tags: partitioning, mount

In my Ubuntu server, I have a sdc disk, and it have sdc1 and sdc2 partition, their TYPE is `part`:

```
suer@suer-S2600CP[/mnt] lsblk                                 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0    60G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   503G  0 part 
└─sda3   8:3    0   1.3T  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0  37.3G  0 part /
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdb5   8:21   0   3.8G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sdb6   8:22   0 182.5G  0 part /home
sdc      8:32   0   3.7T  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   0   1.8T  0 part 
└─sdc2   8:34   0   1.8T  0 part
```

When I mount it, there shows error:

```
suer@suer-S2600CP[/mnt] sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/sdc1          
mount：you must specify the file system type
```

but I cannot mount like this:

```
suer@suer-S2600CP[/mnt] sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/sdc1 -t part  
mount：Unknown file system type “part”
```

---

I use the `lsblk --fs`, there is no FSTYPE:

```
suer@suer-S2600CP[/mnt] lsblk --fs                              
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL MOUNTPOINT
sda                 
├─sda1              
├─sda2              
└─sda3              
sdb                 
├─sdb1              /
├─sdb2              
├─sdb5              [SWAP]
└─sdb6              /home
sdc                 
├─sdc1              
└─sdc2
```

and I use the `lsblk -oname,fstype,mountpoint`:

```
suer@suer-S2600CP[/mnt] lsblk -oname,fstype,mountpoint          
NAME   FSTYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           
├─sda1        
├─sda2        
└─sda3        
sdb           
├─sdb1        /
├─sdb2        
├─sdb5        [SWAP]
└─sdb6        /home
sdc           
├─sdc1        
└─sdc2
```

when I use the `-t auto`:

```
suer@suer-S2600CP[/mnt] sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/sdc1 -t auto  
mount：you must specify the file system type
```

Comment: So `/dev/sdc1` appears to be a "bare" partition that doesn't yet contain a filesystem

Comment: Try `sudo lsblk --fs` command.   You should at least be seeing what FileSystem it is with your / mount which is not showing.  What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: @aircraft based on your updated question, it seems like there is no filesystem on the partition that you are trying to mount. Do you believe that it should have a filesystem? if so, what type?